# Catch Yarn Exit code 1

Tags: jenkins, cypress, yarnpkg, groovyshell

I use a shell script in my jenkins pipeline to execute nodeja actions.
It looks like

```
which yarn || npm install -g yarn

Xvfb :96 -ac -screen 0 1900x1200x24 &
export DISPLAY=:96
#x11vnc start
x11vnc -display $DISPLAY -bg -nopw -xkb &

cd cypress
make build

yarn precy:run
              
yarn stest

yarn report:merge 
yarn report:generate
yarn report:copyScreenshots
```

The line `yarn stest` execute the cypress tests and if one fails, it send an exit code 1.

```
16:02:25  ERROR: Test failures!
16:02:25  ERROR: script returned exit code 1
```

My problem is, that the shell script ends here when exit code 1 is thrown. the lines;

```
yarn report:merge 
yarn report:generate
yarn report:copyScreenshots
```

are not executed anymore. Is there a way to catch the exit code 1 from the stest and still run the following lines well? The following lines create reports and I will need them in success and also in failures.